# Question on ideal triangulation and geodesic lamination

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, curves-and-surfaces

> Q1. Does a closed hyperbolic surface admit an ideal triangulation?

Here, an ideal triangulation of a surface means a partition of a surface by geodesics such that each component of the complement region is an interior of an ideal triangle and each geodesics is an edge of an embedded ideal triangle as a component. So, taking an ideal triangulation of a pair of pants and gluing them up to make a closed surface is not allowed here.

I know these are known for some compact surfaces, for example, a pair of pants. For the non-compact case, if a punctured surface has a negative Euler characteristic, then it admits an ideal triangulation. But I can't find any result on ideal triangulation on a *closed* surface. So I thought like this: If $L$ is a stable geodesic lamination of a pseudo-Anosov on a closed surface $S_g$, then we can add some isolated leaves to make every component of the principal region (i.e. $S_g-L$) an ideal triangle. But because of non-boundary leaves, I can't simply say this is an ideal triangulation of $S_g$. Is it possible?

This makes me come up with other questions for which I also can't find any reference:

> Q2. Does a stable geodesic lamination on a closed surface have infinitely many leaves?

Comment: Can you not cut the surface into pairs of pants and then triangulate each pair of pants with ideal triangles?

Comment: @Neal That will include closed curves on the boundaries of pairs of pants.

Comment: You should start by defining what you mean by a triangulation in this setting. (The usual definition does not apply.) Answer to 2 is positive and "infinite" actually means "continuum." Your 3rd question is unclear.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Do you know any reference for the answer to 2? I deleted Q3 because I think it's nonsense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to question 1 is "no".  Suppose that $S$ is the given closed surface.  Let $\ell = \{ \ell_i \}$ be the collection of geodesics.  In your definition of ideal triangulation, you require that all of the $\ell_i$ arise as boundaries.  Thus none of the $\ell_i$ are closed.  So each $\ell_i$ is a an embedded non-closed geodesic; thus it is a copy of the real line.  So each $\ell_i$ must recur to some fixed open disk.  Thus $\ell$ has accumulation points.  If these accumulation points are in $\ell$ then you obtain geodesics which are not boundary leaves.  If these accumulation points are not in $\ell$ the ideal triangles did not partition the surface.

The answer to question 2 is "yes".  The stable lamination of a pseudo-Anosov map has uncountably many leaves.

---

I suggest the book [Automorphisms of surfaces after Nielsen and Thurston](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/automorphisms-of-surfaces-after-nielsen-and-thurston/2AD58B246E36B971CCB92BD5B923BDB9) as a really excellent introduction to pseudo-Anosov homeomorphisms and also geodesic laminations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I actually questioned Q1 and Q2 (especially Q2) after reading Casson-Bleiler. Could you give any reference for the answer to Q2? It‘s not written in CB as far as I can see.

Comment: Hmm.  Surprisingly, it seems that they do not state this directly in Chapter 6.  (Or, at least, I could not find it.)  However, they do say that the leaves of the stable lamination give all but countably many leaves of the stable foliation.  It is an exercise to show that the stable foliation has uncountably many leaves.  [Hint: draw a small transversal - how many times does a single leaf meet that transversal?]

Comment: They also "hint" that geodesic laminations without closed leaves are "perfect" (see page 48, Exercise 2).  Now, the cross section of a perfect lamination will again be perfect, and thus uncountable, so this is close to what you want.  It is true that the stable lamination of a pseudo-Anosov map is perfect, so they sort of answer their own exercise... But I have always been puzzled by the presence of this exercise so early in the book - it seems impossible to answer without reading the rest of the book!

Comment: If I understand correctly, your point is that a single leaf can cross a transversal only countably many times (is this something obvious?) but a cross-section of the stable lamination is a Cantor set so there should be uncountably many leaves. Am I right?
Btw, CB says if $L$ is a geodesic lamination without closed leaves, then $L'$ is perfect (Theorem 4.7.1).

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly, and no, it is not obvious (but it is doable - use geometry).  Yes, you are right about getting a Cantor set of intersections with a cross section.  And finally, CB say that, but they don't actually tell you where the original $L$ comes from... and also $L'$ could be empty... so Theorem 4.7.1 does not actually solve the exercise.

Comment: I think the countable thing is because a lift of a leaf to $\Bbb H^2$ is at most countable? (I guess it's finite but I can't come up with the proof)

Comment: It is countable, but not finite.  This is because every leaf is dense in the lamination.

Comment: I mean a single lift of a leaf, not a full preimage. Since $\pi_1$ here is finitely generated and a single lift of a leaf is a single geodesic in $\Bbb H^2$ (because I can choose a point and a direction which completely determines a geodesic), transversal and a leaf can meet countably many times.

Comment: You have shown that a leaf and the transversal meet at most countably many times (but perhaps finitely).  I am suggesting that they meet exactly countably (infinitely) many times.

Comment: That's a Poincare recurrence, isn't it?

Comment: Hmm.  Perhaps?  I have not thought about it that way.  Could work...

Comment: @onepotatotwopotato See my answer here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418797/measured-geodesic-laminations-have-either-discrete-or-cantor-set-local-cross-sec/455458#455458.   The transverse intersection of a closed arc and a measured lamination which doesn't consist of closed curves is a Cantor set, which is uncountable.